# How to target the close button in a dialog window frame?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery dialog and I would like to add some functionality to the close button in the upper right and corner of the dialog frame. Can I accomplish this by simply adding a close function to the dialog without it affecting the cancel button contained within the dialog? Meaning the cancel button obviously closes the dialog and performs its own function but the close button in the dialog frame needs to do something else. Hopefully I have explained that clearly enough.

Comment: Mind providing an example code snippet? As far as I understand the question: Give the button an ID and target the functionality accordingly `<button id="close-btn">` and `$('#close-btn').click(function(){...});`.

Comment: Did you inspect the button? I'm sure it has some unique ID or class you could use to select it with jQuery/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `buttons` options within the dialog, and one of them is `Cancel`, then yes. You can obviously create your own function for the `Cancel` button and then a seperate one with the `close` event. Just to be safe, you'll probably want to include `preventDefault()` in the function for your `Cancel` button.

```
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        buttons: {
               "Ok" : function() {
                       //perform whatever
               },
               "Cancel" : function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       //perform whatever
               },
        close: function() {
               // perform special CLOSE function
        }
});
```

Comment: FYI.. if you want to more specifically act upon the close button, it is `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used this method below to accomplish this. It seems to work just fine so I don't know if there are any drawbacks with going this way. Here is the code:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
   ...dialog code goes here...
  }).bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
    ... dialog close code goes here...
  });
```

I suppose the answer above is better as it is clearer and cleaner implementation.